# Implementing Rails callbacks with 'alias' keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was playing around with implementing Rails model callbacks (after_save, before_save) etc. using alias method. All it does is it aliases the `save` method to `save_with_callbacks`. It works, except `before_save` has to be called after `save` is defined or `alias` keyword throws an error. I'm still in the process of understanding how Rails callbacks really works, but was wondering if there's a way to use before_filter anywhere in the model.

```
module ClassMethods
  def before_save
    class_eval do
      # old_save points to save
      # save points to save_with_callbacks
      alias :old_save :save
      alias :save :save_with_callbacks
    end
  end
end

module InstanceMethods
  def save_with_callbacks
    @save_with_callbacks_text = 'Saving with callbacks'
    old_save
  end
end

class Task
  extend ClassMethods
  include InstanceMethods

  attr_reader :save_text, :save_with_callbacks_text

  def save
    @save_text = 'Saving'
  end

  # Needs to be called after save, save_with_callbacks are defined
  before_save
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot users don't generally define 'save' method, but let ORM do it for you. Moved `save` method to `InstanceMethods` and that solves the problem.